# Django - Edit data in db

Tags: python, django

I have a question regarding editing/saving data in database using Django.

I have template that show data from database. And after each record i have link that link you to edit page. 
But now is the question how to edit data in db without using admin panel?

I run thought tutorial in djangobook but i didn't see how to achieve this without using the shell

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Working with forms" section](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) in the Django documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django authenticaion system to create users and giving them permissions to modify the data.